# Ошибка при заполнение базы mdb openldap - ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)

Tags: linux, ldap

Имеется Fedora 36 и openldap 2.6.3. При заполнении базы выходит ошибка для пользователей и групп

```
    ldapadd -xWD cn=root,dc=maintlab,dc=ru  -f passwd.ldif
```

текст ошибки

```
    Adding new entry "uid=root,ou=People,dc=maintlab,dc=ru" 
    ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

и

ldapadd -xWD cn=root,dc=maintlab,dc=ru  -f group.ldif

```
   adding new entry "cn=root,ou=Group,dc=maintlab,dc=ru"
   ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

Файл slapd.conf

```
    moduleload accesslog.la
    moduleload allop.la
    moduleload auditlog.la
    moduleload autoca.la
    moduleload back_asyncmeta.la
    moduleload back_dnssrv.la
    moduleload back_ldap.la
    moduleload back_meta.la
    moduleload back_null.la
    moduleload back_passwd.la
    moduleload back_relay.la
    moduleload back_sock.la
    moduleload check_password.la
    moduleload collect.la
    moduleload constraint.la
    moduleload dds.la
    moduleload deref.la
    moduleload dyngroup.la
    moduleload dynlist.la
    moduleload home.la
    moduleload lloadd.la
    moduleload memberof.la
    moduleload otp.la
    moduleload pcache.la
    moduleload ppolicy.la
    moduleload refint.la
    moduleload remoteauth.la
    moduleload retcode.la
    moduleload rwm.la
    moduleload seqmod.la
    moduleload smbk5pwd.la
    moduleload sssvlv.la
    moduleload syncprov.la
    moduleload translucent.la
    moduleload unique.la
    moduleload valsort.la
```

загружаемый файл group.ldif

```
    dn: cn=root,ou=Group,dc=maintlab,dc=ru
    objectClass: posixGroup
    objectClass: top
    cn: root
    userPassword: {crypt}x
    gidNumber: 0
```

Загружаемый файл passwd.ldif

```
    dn: uid=root,ou=People,dc=maintlab,dc=ru
    uid: root
    cn: root
    objectClass: account
    objectClass: posixAccount
    objectClass: top
    userPassword: {crypt}x
    loginShell: /bin/bash
    uidNumber: 0
    gidNumber: 0
    homeDirectory: /root
    gecos: root
```

Ругается в обоих случаях, как понимаю, на objectClass. В одном случае posixAccount и account, во втором posixGroup. Хотя они описаны в nis.schema.

```
     include        /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
```

Сталкивался кто с ошибкой? Куда рыть? Эти конфигурации у меня тянулись несколько лет, тут поменяли базу с bdb на mdb, произошли некоторые изменения в синтаксисе команды и вот с заполнением базы не понятно

Answer (score 0):

проблема решилась. Оказывается, что в последних версиях, почему то, автоматически не добавляются схемы ppolicy, cosine и nis.
Решение

```
    ldapadd -c -Y EXTERNAL -Q -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.ldif
    ldapadd -c -Y EXTERNAL -Q -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.ldif
    ldapadd -c -Y EXTERNAL -Q -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/nis.ldif
```